# cURL - Download a file with no extension in URL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl, wget, minecraft

I am trying to download a file from this site https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/economyshopgui. There is a button named "Download Latest File", so I copied the link to that button and pasted into the terminal with the following cURL command:

```
curl -o EconomyShopGUI.jar https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/economyshopgui/files/latest
```

and also tried the following command to see what it would download

```
curl -O https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/economyshopgui/files/latest
```

I tried to search some results online and to put `curl -L -O` or `curl -O -J -L`. I tried everything and maybe there is no way to do what I asked. Hope that someone could give me an explanation or solution. I can't download from browser because, so that's my only way to DL something.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the `-L`, `--location` option:

```
curl -Lo EconomyShopGUI.jar https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/economyshopgui/files/latest
```

#### Explanation

The URL returns a 302 redirect to `/error?aspxerrorpath=/projects/economyshopgui/files/latest`. This can be seen by making a HEAD request instead of a GET request:

```
$ curl -I https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/economyshopgui/files/latest
HTTP/2 302
date: Wed, 17 Nov 2021 20:58:33 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
set-cookie: AWSALB=XPIy/kG6YB43FiNyWSi8BpsIA6YAUWahl8p7PGFVzlb3MOocdKfR/WUYuEZhMHDI0jX9fwmOYUZds4nzi/D8MJmmRH4j2/snJ9iFftX1dxsnm1ECV3YtsCf9nl2y; Expires=Wed, 24 Nov 2021 20:58:33 GMT; Path=/
cache-control: private
location: /error?aspxerrorpath=/projects/economyshopgui/files/latest
...
```

The `-L`, `--location` option instructs `curl` to follow such redirections:

> If the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different
> location (indicated with a Location: header and a 3XX response code), this
> option will make curl redo the request on the new place.

#### Alternative solution

You could use `wget` instead of `curl`:

```
 wget --content-disposition  https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/economyshopgui/files/latest
```

With the `--content-disposition` option, this automatically saves the output to `EconomyShopGUI-3.9.2.jar`. Without it, the resulting file would be saved with the not-very-useful name, `latest`.

Comment: The OP said they'd already tried `-L` and it didn't work for them